# Will CUDA speed up moving lots of data from Excel sheets into a database?

Tags: excel-2007, gpu, cuda.net

I'm developing a program that moves a lot of data from Excel Sheets to a database. Is it possible for something like CUDA to speed up the process? Is it possible for me to use it to open more than one sheet at once and have different cores sharing the work?

Comment: Unless you're doing lots of processing on this data before chucking it to the database, I would expect you to be limited by how fast you can read the data in from disk/write to the database. Speeding up your code is likely to result in minimal (if any) performance improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUDA can speed up computational processing, but not bottlenecks due to network bandwidth / latency, or slow (compared to the rest of your application/machine) IO performance. In your case, you are probably not putting a lot of stress on your CPU, so your code will most likely not benefit from offloading code to the GPU.

**Edit**: Basically, what Anon says.

Answer (score 2):

No. CUDA speeds up data processing.

If you were doing a bunch of number crunching, it may help you. But simply extracting data from excel and bulk inserting to a database has nothing to do with CUDA.